# Dialogflow not detecting Line location message

Tags: line, dialogflow-es, line-api

I am struggling with Line location message.
My webhook is sending the action button to prompt the user with the location sharing view and then the location is sent back (theoretically) to Dialogflow and then to the webhook.
But the location message, when sent back, is never detected/interpreted by Dialogflow nor the webhook.
I don’t see anything happening on both sides, as if the message was never send.

Location message send from the webhook to give the user the possibility to send back he’s location :

```
{
  "line": {
    "type": "template",
    "altText": "this is a buttons template",
    "template": {
      "type": "buttons",
      "thumbnailImageUrl": "https://example.com/bot/images/image.jpg",
      "title": "Menu",
      "text": "Please select",
      "actions": [
        {
          "type": "uri",
          "label": "View detail",
          "uri": "line://nv/location"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As mentioned in Line’s Messaging API Reference the location message send from the user should look like this :

```
{
    "type": "location",
    "title": "my location",
    "address": "〒150-0002 東京都渋谷区渋谷２丁目２１−１",
    "latitude": 35.65910807942215,
    "longitude": 139.70372892916203
}
```

I don’t understand why nothing is happening, if someone as an idea, please help me.
Thanks !